# Extract last string between brackets from a string - python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to know the way for extracting the last string between brackets from a long string. So I need a function, `extract_last`, for example, that let me get an output like that:

```
>> extract_last('(hello) my (name) is (Luis)')
>> 'Luis'
```

How can I accomplish that without using a for, I am looking for the smartest way.

The for way that I have implemented works. I have no tested it with all the possibilities, but the simplest things do it well:

```
def extract_last(string):
    bracket_found = False
    characters = []
    for character in string[::-1]:
        if character == ')':
            bracket_found = True
            continue
        if(character == '(' and bracket_found):
            break;
       if(bracket_found and character != ')'):
            characters.append(character)
    return ''.join(characters[::-1])
```

But this solution has many lines and I know that using regular expressions or something like that, I could accomplish that with a one-or-two-lines solution.

Comment: Why? Why not using `for`? What have you tried?

Comment: Your regular expression could start with a greedy `.*`.

Comment: your regex can look for words inside parens, and capture them (with parens): `regex = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')`. If you run `regex.findall(<whatever>)`, you get an array with all the matches. Then get the last one with bracket access (`[-1]`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
s = '(hello) my (name) is (Luis)'
re.sub('^.*\((.*?)\)[^\(]*$', '\g<1>', s) # Search for the content between the last set of brackets
# 'Luis'
```

Of you could do a search on all brackets:

```
l = re.findall('\((.*?)\)', s) # Search for all brackets (and store their content)
#['hello', 'name', 'Luis']
theOne = l[-1] # Get the last one
#'Luis'
```

Comment: I have chosen your answer because it has in account spaces in the string between  brackets. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

def extract_last(val):
    r = re.findall(r'\((\w+)\)', val)
    return r[-1] if r else None
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `split` or `rsplit` would be one way of doing it

```
>>> a= '(hello) my (name) is (Luis)'
>>> a.split('(')[-1].split(')')[0]
'Luis'
>>> a.rsplit('(')[-1].rsplit(')')[0]
'Luis'
>>>
```

Where [-1] is the last item found and [0] is the first

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to use regex here. Simply use [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to split the string at the last occurrence of `(` then [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the `)` from the slicing result.

```
>>> string = '(hello) my (name) is (Luis)'
>>> string.rpartition('(')[-1].strip(')')
'Luis'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use split function to get sub-string,
you can try this :

```
def extract_last(my_string):
    temp = my_string.split(" ")
    print temp[-1]   ## get last element

extract_last('(hello) my (name) is (Luis)')
```

now temp contains all words seperated by " "(spaces) 
just read from last and get your value

Comment: Please see the OP's result which is not same as yours.

Comment: it can be that the last word is not the last enclosed one. e.g., `'(hello) my (name) is Luis'`. Here OP would like to get `'name'`.